# Restore Ion toggle state from local storage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a small problem with ionic. I have this toggle 
`<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="Bouleau" (ionChange)="saveSetting(Bouleau)" checked="bouleau"></ion-toggle>`

I would like the toggle takes the value of "bouleau" which is a bool on the launch of my app. The problem is : even if I put `checked = true` the toggle doesn't check.

My var bouleau is correctly store and correctly restore, but I don't know how to display it.

```
    getSettings(){
     this.storage.get('mysettings').then((mysettings) => {
      console.log('Your settings are', mysettings);
      if( mysettings.bouleau == true){
       console.log("I'm true");
      }else{
       console.log("I'm false")
      }
     });
```

Thanks

Comment: Just declare variable as a model for this component, and fill it in constructor with data from your local storage. Your model is deciding, about that component is check or not.

Comment: Thanks it works !

Comment: @rf_96_rf please add that as an answer so that it can be accepted for future users to see :)

Comment: Yes it's done thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare variable as a model for this component, and then fill it in constructor with data from your local storage.

```
public Bouleau: boolean = false;
...
constructor(..., storage: Storage){
   ...
   storage.get('mysettings').then(mysettings) => {
      this.Bouleau = mysettings.bouleau;
   };
   ...
}
```

Variable Bouleau makes component selected or not. I declared first as a false, cus reading data from storage is an asynchrous method, and it need some time (you also can add loadingcontroller)